# cypress-cucumber-preprocessor unused step definition

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to clean my code.

I have some features like :
login.feature

```
Feature: Login Test

  Scenario: Sign in with an invalid password and good email
    Given I open my page and I'm not registered
    When I sign in with an invalid password and a good email
    Then I get an error message displayed
```

login.ts

```
Given('I open my page and I\'m not registered', () => {
  cy.visit(url);
});

When('I sign in with an invalid password and a good email', () => {
  cy.get('input[name=username]').type(`username`));
  cy.get('input[name=password]').type(`password`);
  cy.contains('Sign In').click();
});
Then('I get an error message displayed', () => {
  cy.contains('Invalid username or password.');
});

And('Unused step definition', () => {
  //unused step definition
});
```

I developped with intellij idea ultimate

I want to know what's the step unused. Is it possible with intellij idea?
I tried the analyse -> run inspection by name -> strike out deprecated steps

but I got nothing (and in the cucumber+ tab, I've nothing too, seems like it did not find any features.)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, with IntelliJ, you have the nice plugin (cucumber.js) to know if a step is not defined. But you don't have any plugin to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, I used the plugin to create my step so it can tell me if it's not defined. 
but I cleaned my gherkin, and so badly something, I forget to clean the step definition behind

Comment: It doesn't exist. What you can try is one by one checking the step. But long and time-consuming.